# MPPE difficulties on OSX PPTP VPN server

Tags: macos, vpn, encryption, pptp

I'm trying to get a VPN up and running again on a Mac OSX server, and seem to have run into a snag with MPPE. When I try and connect to the VPN from my laptop on the same local network, I get the following messages in `/var/log/ppp/vpnd.log`

```
2015-07-14 17:01:45 MDT Incoming call... Address given to client = xx.xxx.xx.xxx
Tue Jul 14 17:01:45 2015 : Directory Services Authentication plugin initialized
Tue Jul 14 17:01:45 2015 : Directory Services Authorization plugin initialized
Tue Jul 14 17:01:45 2015 : PPTP incoming call in progress from '192.168.1.154'...
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : PPTP connection established.
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : using link 0
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : Using interface ppp0
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : Connect: ppp0 <--> socket[34:17]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x4c905d23> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x5dd17fa9> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFACK.
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x5dd17fa9> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x4c905d23> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x4c905d23]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : sent [CHAP Challenge id=0x43 <2a596a4a75602b4946642a2d1b12050b>, name = "server"]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x5dd17fa9]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : rcvd [CHAP Response id=0x43 <afb93f9351af212c460cf851eaf6d0580000000000000000e1bda0d312f0542755399c6ca465b7a8878439608d30f16100>, name = "admin"]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : sent [CHAP Success id=0x43 "S=3B614827970F82512A68E1022EF6F7FC0AF4FA3F M=Access granted"]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : CHAP peer authentication succeeded for admin
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : DSAccessControl plugin: User 'admin' authorized for access
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S +L -D -C>]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : rcvd [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : MPPE required but peer negotiation failed
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "MPPE required but peer negotiation failed"]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : Connection terminated.
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : sent [CCP ConfRej id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : Connect time 0.0 minutes.
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : Sent 0 bytes, received 0 bytes.
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : PPTP disconnecting...
Tue Jul 14 17:01:46 2015 : PPTP disconnected
2015-07-14 17:01:46 MDT    --> Client with address = xx.xxx.xx.xxx has hungup
```

What I gather from searching online (particularly [here](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#mppe_rbpnf)) is that there is an encryption mismatch between the client and the server. I can't bring up a graphical environment on my server, so I've been configuring it over ssh. The applicable file on the server seems to be `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.RemoteAccessServers.plist`, which has the following lines relating to MPPE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>ActiveServers</key>
        <array>
                <string>com.apple.ppp.pptp</string>
        </array>
        <key>Servers</key>
                ...
                <key>com.apple.ppp.pptp</key>
                <dict>
                        ...
                        <key>PPP</key>
                        <dict>
                                ...
                                <key>CCPProtocols</key>
                                <array>
                                        <string>MPPE</string>
                                </array>
                                ...
                                <key>MPPEKeySize128</key>
                                <integer>1</integer>
                                <key>MPPEKeySize40</key>
                                <integer>1</integer>
                                ...
                        </dict>
                        ...
                </dict>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This looks like it should be configured to work with both 40-bit and 128-bit MPPE key sizes. On my server, there are no files in `/etc/ppp/`. On the client, I have files in `/etc/ppp/`, but everything related to MPPE seems to be commented out in `/etc/ppp/options.pptp`

```
# Encryption
# (There have been multiple versions of PPP with encryption support,
# choose with of the following sections you will use.  Note that MPPE
# requires the use of MSCHAP-V2 during authentication)

# http://ppp.samba.org/ the PPP project version of PPP by Paul Mackarras
# ppp-2.4.2 or later with MPPE only, kernel module ppp_mppe.o
# {{{
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
#require-mppe-128
# }}}

# http://polbox.com/h/hs001/ fork from PPP project by Jan Dubiec
# ppp-2.4.2 or later with MPPE and MPPC, kernel module ppp_mppe_mppc.o
# {{{
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
#mppe required,stateless
# }}}
```

I tried uncommenting the various mppe lines (even with and without the triple curly braces, which I couldn't discern whether they meant anything). Initiating VPN connections got the same `MPPE required but peer negotiation failed` message every time.

On my client I'm running pppd version 2.4.5. On the server, trying to run any options with pppd gives me the message

```
pppd: Can't open options file /etc/ppp/options: No such file or directory
```

so I'm not sure which version is running on the server.

Any ideas for what else I should be trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now I feel stupid. It turns out MPPE was indeed enabled on the server. I hadn't enabled MPPE on my client, though!

I'm running Linux Mint 17 XFCE on my client, so to enable MPPE I clicked on the network indicator plugin in my system tray and under "VPN Connections" selected "Configure VPN...". From there I selected the VPN I wanted to configure and clicked "Edit...". Under the "VPN" tab I clicked the "Advanced..." button. Under "Security and Compression" there is a checkbox labelled "Use Point-to-Point encryption (MPPE)". Once I checked that box and clicked "OK" and "Save", I was able to connect to the VPN without any problems.